# Show that an application is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, analysis

I am studying the notes of an undergraduate probability course and I arrived this exercise.

Let $D = (0,n) \times (0, \infty)$ where $n >0$. Show thatn $T(x,y) = (x,xy)$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $D$ on itself.

I've never studied this topic before and I went to read about it. In order to prove the required, I must show that it is a smooth map, has an inverse and differentiable.

With the help of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism), I calculated the Jacobian matrix and its determinant $= x$. The Jacobian matrix has zero determinant if and only if $x = 0$ so how could I conclude that there is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism ?

Comment: The Jacobian is based on partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y.$ It is actually possible for those to exist at every point in the domain even though there are points at which the function is not differentiable. Those two partial derivatives will tell you that a certain plane is a tangent plane if there is a tangent plane, but it may fail to be a tangent plane because it does not agree with the directional derivative in some direction other than the $x$- and $y$-directions, for example at a $45^\circ$ angle to both of those.

Comment: I'm mildly surprised that you encountered this in an undergraduate probability course. Usually you'll see things that say something like $\text{“}$Suppose $X,Y$ are independent and have gamma distributions with the same scale parameter and different shape parameters. Find the distribution of $(U,V) = (X+Y,\,\, X/(X+Y))\text{.''}$ Then of course you're expected to find the Jacobian determinant so you can evaluate the integrals. But I haven't seen one that gets strictly rigorous about these second-year calculus techniques.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for your comment. In fact, this a self study and I didn't see in the notes "I have" the things you mentioned in your second comment

Answer (score 1):

The inverse function is $(u,v) \mapsto (u, v/u)$ which is $C^1$.

If you want to use the Jacobian, then you can use the inverse function theorem to conclude that your map is a local diffeomorphism (meaning that around every point there exists a nbhd such that the map is a diffeomorphism onto the image). However, you will still need to check that your map is bijective by hand (the Jacobian will not help you to get around that).

Comment: so as I understood the Jacobian matrix here will make things harder. How did you concluded that the application is $C^1-$diffeomorphism directly after finding the inverse function? and for sure thanks a lot :)

Comment: Well, if you have the inverse function, you just need to check that it is $C^1$. In this case it is easy to see that it really is $C^1$.

Comment: However, in general if you can show that the Jacobian is always invertible and the map itself is bijective, then you can conclude that the function is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism. This is really useful as in general we cannot hope to explicitely find the inverse function. This is what makes this inverse function theorem for analysts so appealing :)

Comment: Concerning my last question and your answer, the justification is based on the inverse function theorem  which states that if J(f) is invertible, then f is a local diffeomorphism ?

Comment: Indeed, the inverse function theorem gives local diffeo.

Comment: Excuse me for all of these annoying questions but as I explained all of this is new to me. What I meant, Finding the inverse function then using the inverse function method is considered a complete answer for the question "class $C^1$" or what? and please forgive me :)

Comment: There are two usual ways to show something is a $C^1$-diffeo: 1.) Find the inverse function and directly check that the inverse function is $C^1$. Quite often that is not possible as we cannot compute the inverse explicitely. Then we try to use 2.) We show that the function is bijective (ie the inverse function exists) and then check that the determinant of the Jacobian is nowhere zero. Then we conclude with the inverse function theorem that indeed this map is a $C^1$-diffeo.